# Difference between `function` and `let` blocks in Julia?

Tags: function, julia, let

In Julia, is there any difference at all between these to <s>two</s> three ways of creating a function:

- With keyword `function`

```
function g1(x)
   # compute something, store it in `result`
   return result # (return keyword is optional)
end
```

- With keyword `let`

```
g2(x) = let
   # compute something, store it in `result`
   return result # (return keyword is optional)
end
```

- With keyword `begin`

```
g3(x) = begin
   # compute something, store it in `result`
   return result # (return keyword is optional)
end
```

The answer below is: these three definitions are **exactly equivalent**.

**EDIT**: clarify the question, and emphasis on the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the `let` variant also creates a function. Therefore you could also write:

```
g2(x) = begin
   # compute something, store it in `result`
   result
end
```

to get the same effect.

The reason is that all after `=` here is within `g2` function scope, so no matter if you do `begin`-`end` or `let`-`end` the expression is in this scope. The `let` variant creates an extra hard scope, but it does not change anything as there is nothing in the function scope that is not in `let` scope in your example.

`let`-`end` would make a difference from `begin`-`end` if it were in a global scope, but in your case you introduce it within function scope.

Comment: So one can create exactly the same function either with `function`, (optional return in the end), and `end`, OR, with `= begin`, no return, `end`, OR, with `= let`, no return, `end`. The three are exactly equivalent. Is that right?

Comment: Correction: `return` is also allowed in both `let` and `begin` blocks, because they are within a function definition.

Comment: They are equivalent in terms of behavior in this case. As the Julia Manual specifies "In the assignment form, the body of the function must be a single expression, although it can be a compound expression". And yes - `return` is allowed in all options just like everywhere within function scope. You can check that you get the same using the `@code_warntype` macro.